# Kotlin espresso UI testing with RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I used espresso before in java and scrolling RecyclerView or performing click on particular child of recyclerView was pretty easy. Something like this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView))
.perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()))
```

But in kotlin I can not use RecyclerViewActions. Can someone show me how to perform scrolling and clicking on RecyclerView. Thanks!

Comment: It's the same usage in both Kotlin and Java, what was the error you got? Maybe the error could give you a hint.

Comment: @Aaron error is "unresolved refference" on RecyclerViewActions. I can not use it

Comment: @Aaron sorry mate i didn't add espresso contrib dependency, my bad. I should really stop coding at these late hours :D